# Cramer-Rao lower bound for normal($\theta, 4\theta^2$)

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I am trying to find the Cramer-Rao lower bound for unbiased estimators of $\theta$, given a sample $X_1,\ldots, X_n \sim \textrm{normal}(\theta,4\theta^2)$. I am calculating the CRLB as

$$
\frac{1}{-n\textrm{E}\left[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\log f(x_i\vert\theta)\right]}
$$

Evaluating this I get $\frac{4\theta^2}{9n}$.

For that distribution however, from the exponential family representation I think that $\left(\sum_i x_i, \sum_i x_i^2 \right)$ is a complete sufficient statistic, and therefore any estimator based only on this should achieve the CRLB. But the variance of $\bar{X}$, which is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$ based only on the above, is $\frac{4\theta^2}{n}$ which is larger.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: If $n = 5$ and $\theta = 10$, then $V(\bar X) = 80$. However, my invented estimator $\tilde \theta = (\bar X + .5s)/1.95$ has $E(\tilde \theta) \approx 10$ and $V(\tilde \theta) \approx 24.$ (1) Are you guaranteed that an estimator based on the complete sufficient statistic will achieve the CRLB? (2) If $\sum x_2$ is part of the sufficient statistic, do you suppose it has no role to play?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are a couple things wrong with your reasoning.  First, the result you're alluding to (the Lehmann-Scheffe theorem) requires that a statistic be both sufficient *and* complete.  This particular distribution is a curved exponential family and the statistic $T = (\sum_i X_i, \sum_i X_i^2)$ turns out not to be complete.  We can see this by defining a new statistic $g(T) = n \bar{X}_n^2 / (4 + n) - S_n^2 / 4$ where $S_n^2$ is the sample variance and calculating
\begin{align}
\text{E}[g(T)] &= \frac{n}{4 + n} \text{E} ( \bar{X}_n^2 ) - \frac{1}{4} \text{E} ( S_n^2 ) \\
&= \frac{n}{4 + n} \left ( \text{Var}(\bar{X}_n) + \text{E}(\bar{X}_n)^2 \right ) - \theta^2 \\
&= \frac{n}{4 + n} \left ( \frac{4 \theta^2}{n} + \theta^2 \right ) - \theta^2 \\
&= 0 .
\end{align}
It's not difficult to verify that $g(T)$ is not degenerate at zero, and so $T$ is not a complete statistic.  Secondly, even if it were the conclusion would be that any unbiased function of this statistic would be a UMVUE, which does not guarantee that it achieves the Cramer-Rao lower bound.

Comment: As it stands, this is partly phrased as speculation and commentary, not an Answer.

Comment: @BruceTrumbo Yes the above is an answer I think as the OP says "Where have I gone wrong?"

Comment: He asked where he went wrong, which was in assuming that $(\sum_i X_i, \sum_i X_i^2)$ is complete, and in asserting that a UMVUE must achieve the CRLB.

Comment: OK then, partial answer. The speculation has to do with the sufficient statistic.

Comment: @BruceTrumbo I added a bit more about the completeness part.

Comment: Thanks. Very nice! Even though not complete, it still seems including the SD helps decrease the variance, as per simulated results in my Comment beneath the problem. This Q and your A should make this a useful page for archival purposes.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I thought it was complete is because $\sum_i x_i$ and $\sum_i x_i^2$ come from the exponential family representation. Is it only true that _full rank_ exponential families admit complete sufficient statistics in this manner? Also, for some reason I thought estimators for exponential family distributions achieved the CRLB.

Comment: If there are $p$ parameters and the parameter space contains an open set in $\mathbb{R}^p$, then the sufficient statistic will also be complete.  In this case the parameter space is a single curve through $\mathbb{R}^2$, which doesn't contain any two dimensional open sets.  I'm not sure if UMVUEs in exponential family settings always achieve the CRLB, but it's possible.